# How to run ng-serve with expressjs?

Tags: angular, express

I'm doing this [Angular6/Express tutorial](https://www.djamware.com/post/5b00bb9180aca726dee1fd6d/mean-stack-angular-6-crud-web-application) and they use:

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng build && node ./bin/www",
  "build": "ng build",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
```

To build the Angular app and I think serve it through the ExpressJS server which runs at port 3000. This works fine. But when I edit some code the build is of course not updated since it uses the build command.

Is it possible to use `ng serve` with the ExpressJS server so I don't have to reboot the server constantly?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly no. `ng serve` specifically is used to develop Angular app. The `start` script above directs to do a build with `ng build` then run `node ./bin/www` to serve the built contents from the previous `ng build`.

You might wanna develop the Angular app on its port (default 4200) and use `ng serve` instead of doing that `start` script.

Comment: Found this source, https://medium.com/@danielkagan/serve-mean-stack-using-angular-cli-f39b33dbad64 kinda does what I wanted to do.

Comment: Nice. But the approach in the article kinda kills the purpose of having the proxy file or actually serve the SPA with your backend using express static. Might as well just use concurrently to serve with proxy and just start server.js without doing ng build altogether, for development purpose. That’s what I’d personally.

Comment: I think that´s what he does though. `"start": "npm run build & concurrently --kill-others \"npm run serve-api\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "serve": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",`

Comment: But the ng build is redundant there ;)

Comment: I supose it is, but it only builds at the start.

Comment: The build is to be used by the backend to serve up the frontend in deployment. The approach above still uses localhost:4200 for the frontend so it’s redundant to run ng build there. Take it off, still same result